# Greensock TweenLite issue when animating border short hand property

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am using Greensock TweenLite and I need to animate a border for a DOM element.

As you can see the inline style is set to:
`border: solid 0px yellow`

and using TweenLite I pass as end result

`border: "solid 20px blue"`

but the animation is not executed.

I would like to know if there is shorthand property are supported and/or if a work around exists.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('target');

TweenLite.to(element, 2, {
  border: "solid 20px blue"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="perspective: 200px">
  <div id="target" style=" width: 250px;  height: 250px; background-color: red; font-size: 100px; border: solid 0px yellow;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **`20px solid blue`**  (not `solid 20px blue`)

```
           ^^^^--- Size goes first
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById('target');
TweenLite.to(element, 2, {border: "20px solid blue"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="perspective: 200px">
  <div id="target" style=" width: 250px;  height: 250px; background-color: red; font-size: 100px; border: solid 0px yellow;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering whether there are documentation on this "Size goes first" rule? I find it rather confusing that it works for CSS but not GSAP.

Comment: I think browsers for CSS can handles any order, but GSAP most probably need to stick with an order in order to interpolate. Here DOC which mention size first `<br-width> || <br-style> || <color>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: @GibboK exactly, browsers lets you mess around with the order, not gSock